# Access Map State ( item ) in Step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to access item properties which I am iterating over using Map state. I keep getting this error:

```
Value ($['Map'].snapshot_id.S) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'. (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6fc02935-c161-49df-8606-bc6f3e2934a6)
```

I have gone through the docs, which seems to suggest access using `$.Map.snapshot_id.S` but doesn't seem to work. Meanwhile, an input item to Map is:

```json
{
  "snapshot_id": {
    "S": "snap-01dd5ee46df84119e"
  },
  "file_type": {
    "S": "bash"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "64e6893261d94669b7a8ca425233d68b"
  },
  "script_s3_link": {
    "S": "df -h"
  }
}
```

Map state definition:

```json
    "Map": {
          "Type": "Map",
          "ItemProcessor": {
            "ProcessorConfig": {
              "Mode": "INLINE"
            },
            "StartAt": "Parallel State",
            "States": {
              "Parallel State": {
                "Comment": "A Parallel state can be used to create parallel branches of execution in your state machine.",
                "Type": "Parallel",
                "Branches": [
                  {
                    "StartAt": "CreateVolume",
                    "States": {
                      "CreateVolume": {
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Parameters": {
                          "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
                          "SnapshotId": "$$.Map.snapshot_id.S"
                        },
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:createVolume",
                        "Next": "AttachVolume"
                      },
                      "AttachVolume": {
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Parameters": {
                          "Device": "MyData",
                          "InstanceId": "MyData",
                          "VolumeId": "MyData"
                        },
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:attachVolume",
                        "End": true
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "End": true
              }
            }
          },
          "Next": "Final Result",
          "ItemsPath": "$.Items",
          "MaxConcurrency": 40
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR `"SnapshotId.$": "$.snapshot_id"`

By default, each inline map iteration's input is [one item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html#inline-map-state-examples) from the [ItemsPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-itemspath.html) array, accessible simply as `$`.

Your state machine definition implies that `$.Items` is an array of objects with a `snapshot_id` key (and other keys).  If so, each iteration's snapshot id is at `$.snapshot_id`.

Finally, adding `.$` to the parameter name (`SnapshotId.$`) tells Step Functions the value is not a literal, but rather a [path value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters) to be substituted.

Comment: you're correct but why am i still getting the error `Value ($.snapshot_id) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'. (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 478cd56a-4c04-4fb5-9245-e41e4b84079e)`

Comment: These are the api parameters i am sending to >>createVolume  `{
  "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
  "SnapshotId": "$.snapshot_id"
}`

Comment: @AtifShafi - You are right, there is one more bug to fix: the parameter name should be `SnapshotId.$`.  See edited answer.